# В чем может быть ошибка при "react build?

Tags: reactjs, vps, node-modules

[[image]react build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrYGg.png)
В чем может быть ошибка при "react build?

package:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "mobx": "^6.6.1",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: сама ошибка говорит о непредвиденной `;` но на самом деле это ни о чем не говорит, нужно больше информации о проекте и желательно в текстовом формате, начать можно с `package.json`

Comment: так же желательно проверить перед билдом проект линтером

Comment: что-то недописано или скобка не закрыта.
А проект без сборки рабоетает?

Comment: Локально да, но на VPS не билдит и не стартует

Comment: такое впечатление что что-то с `jest` тестами не так, возможно их стоит удалить если не используются, как вариант там код не соответствует проекту, я бы прогнал тесты локально для проверки гипотезы